# Vue: emit to view component works only the first time

Tags: vue.js, emit

I have a view which has a recursive component A, which in turn embeds a component B. In component B changes are made, which should be passed via emit to component A and these should be passed directly to the view.

This "chain" works, but only the first time:

Komponent B:

```
// Emit in component B
function emitToParent() {
  console.log("component B: ", props.current.id);
  emits('changeParentReactiveData', props.current.id, data);
}
```

Komponent A:

```
// Receiving the emit in Komponent A and passing it to the view
<component-b @change-parent-reactive-data="emitToParent" />
    
function emitToParent(id, data) {
  console.log("component A: ", id);
  emits("changeParentReactiveData", id, data);
}
```

View:

```
// Receiving the emit in the View
<component-a @change-parent-reactive-data="setReactive" />

function setReactive(id, data) {
  console.log("view: ", id);
}
```

Outcome console.log:

```
component B:  262194
component A:  262194
view:  262194

component B:  262187
component A:  262187

component B:  262193
component A:  262193
```

So as you can see, the last emit to the view component happens only the first time. Why? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you should not use `this.$emit()` instead of `emits()`? The latter is supposed to be an Array rather than a Function. Also, if you have a deep recursion it sounds better to use an event bus instead of recursively re-emitting the event(s).

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention... I'm using `<script setup>` and `const emits = defineEmits(["changeParentReactiveData"]);`. But a colleague of mine just asked "why don't you put it in the store directly"... I'm not sure why I haven't thought about this, but I'm gonna try this approach so I probably don't need to push it all the way up to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, As I am not able to setup the Vue 3 in the below code snippet. I am demoing it using Vue 2 setup. Please have a look and try to find out the root cause of the issue you are facing.

Every time you will click on `Click Me` text in the inner child component. It is emitting the events properly.

```js
Vue.component('childComponent', {
  template: `<div class="emit-time" @click="click()">Click me (Component A)</div>`,
  methods: {
    click() {
      console.log('component A');
      this.$emit('clickup', 'a click');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('ParentComponent', {
  data() {
    return {
      message: null
    }
  },
  template: `<div><p v-text="message"></p><child-component @clickup="localMethod"></child-component></div>`,
  methods: {
    localMethod() {
      console.log('component B');
      this.message = 'Component B invoked and emitted the event to the parent';
      this.$emit('clickup', 'a click');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: null
  },
  methods: {
    localMethod() {
      console.log('Root component');
      this.message = 'Top most parent invoked'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  padding : 20px;
}
div {
  padding : 10px;
  border : 1px dashed black;
}
div ~ div {
  margin-top : 10px;
  border-color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-text="message"></p>
  <parent-component @clickup="localMethod"></parent-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as it is. I have set up a [demo here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) and it is working just fine. Maybe you can match your code with this-

`View.vue`

```
<script setup>
import Comp1 from './Comp1.vue'

const setReactive = (payload) => {
  console.log('View', payload);
};
</script>
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Comp1 @change-parent-reactive-data="setReactive" />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

`Component 1`

```
<script setup>
import Comp2 from './Comp2.vue'
  
const emits = defineEmits(['changeParentReactiveData'])
    
const emitToParent = (payload) => {
  console.log('Component A', payload);
  emits('changeParentReactiveData', payload);
};
</script>
<template>
  <Comp2 @change-parent-reactive-data="emitToParent" :some-prop="262194"></Comp2>
</template>
```

`Component 2`

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['someProp']);
const emits = defineEmits(['changeParentReactiveData'])
  
const emitToParent = () => {
  console.log('Component B', props.someProp);
  emits('changeParentReactiveData', props.someProp);
};
</script>
<template>
  <v-btn @click="emitToParent()">
    click
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try implementing a global event bus to pass values from component to component.
Here's a blog to explain how:
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/